# Order by Field in cosmos sql query

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

In mysql we have ORDER BY FIELD(status,'OnBoarded','Expired','Invited');

I need the same for Azure CosmosDB sql to sort the records with required order of my enum 'InvitedStatus'.

Below are example records.

```
{
    "LastName": "ExpiredUser",
    "FirstName": "Name",
    "id": "cimata5282@shopxda.com",
    "Role": "Administrator",
    "InvitedStatus": "Expired",
},
{
     "LastName": "InvitedUser",
    "FirstName": "Name",
    "id": "cimata5282@shopxda.com",
    "Role": "Administrator",
    "InvitedStatus": "Invited",
}
,
{
    "LastName": "OnboardedUser",
    "FirstName": "Name",
    "id": "cimata5282@shopxda.com",
    "Role": "Administrator",
    "InvitedStatus": "OnBoarded",
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show your query, along with what the expected vs actual output is. It's unclear, currently, what your issue is.

Comment: As I mentioned above Iam not able to find a query in azure sql api . I would like to know whether azure support such api of order by field. I would like to sort the records shown above sorted by "InvitedStatus:" in specific order